# .htaccess redirect to default url with /nl/ for language

Tags: .htaccess

If a user has by default English browsers he should be redirected to domainname.nl/nl/home/
But I have no idea how to fix this in .htaccess
Who can help me with this.
I appreciate your help.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule as very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en- [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!nl/home/).*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your solution fits for all page following after domain.nl/nl/
example:
    domain.nl/nl/pagelink1
    domain.nl/nl/pagelink2
    domain.nl/nl/pagelink3
It is only the browser language that always must redirected to /nl/